# ntp-4.2.8.p10-1 fails after upgrade due to libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (installed 1.1) dependency and wants downgrade to 4.2.8.p9-2. How does that make sense?

Tags: arch-linux, openssl, pacman, ntpd, yaourt

#### Disclaimer:

*This really is not a major issue critical to the stable operation of my system but I am asking this because I simply can't make any sense of it and I would really like to know what is going on here.*

---

I am running an `arch linux` box and just did `yaourt -Syua`. Everything went fine. I did a reboot and checked `systemctl list-units --state failed` to see `ntpd.service` as a result. I `journalctl -r -u ntpd` and found the entry

```
Apr 24 19:54:33 htpc ntpd[1850]: /usr/bin/ntpd: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Running `ldconfig -v | grep libcrypto` yielded

```
libcrypto.so.1.1 -> libcrypto.so.1.1
```

Which in turn belongs to `openssl`

```
# yaourt -Ql | grep libcrypto
openssl /usr/lib/libcrypto.so
openssl /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

I then thought maybe something didn't upgrade the first time I ran `yaourt -Syua` so I tried a second time with no upgrade candidates. And the most likely candidate would be `ntp` anyway given that `openssl` was upgraded successfully

```
# yaourt -Si openssl | grep Version && yaourt -Qi openssl | grep Version
Version         : 1.1.0.e-1
Version         : 1.1.0.e-1
```

Checking `ntp`version

```
# yaourt -Si ntp | grep Version && yaourt -Qi ntp | grep Version
Version         : 4.2.8.p9-2   // in the offical `Extra` repo
Version         : 4.2.8.p10-1  // installed on my system??
```

Just to see what would happen I tried to (re-)install `ntp`

```
# yaourt -Sy ntp
:: Synchronising package databases...
core is up to date
extra is up to date
archlinuxfr is up to date
community is up to date
multilib is up to date
warning: downgrading package ntp (4.2.8.p10-1 => 4.2.8.p9-2)
Packages (1) ntp-4.2.8.p9-2

Total Download Size:    1.71 MiB
Total Installed Size:   4.09 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      -0.10 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

This then completely flustered me. It wants me to downgrade `ntp` when I just upgraded `openssl` in order to use the correct `libcrypto.so`?

```
# cat /var/log/pacman.log | grep openssl
[2017-04-24 19:23] [ALPM] upgraded openssl (1.0.2.k-1 -> 1.1.0.e-1)

# cat /var/log/pacman.log | grep ntp
[2017-04-13 18:08] [ALPM] upgraded ntp (4.2.8.p9-1 -> 4.2.8.p10-1)
```

Also when looking at the official Arch Linux site, it says for the `ntp`package its outdated stating `ntp 4.2.8.p9-2` as the current version.

#### My Questions

- How is it possible that I have a newer `ntp`version than stated in the official `Extra` repository while I only have one other custom repository (`[archlinuxfr]` - for yaourt) that does not carry `ntp`? I checked.
- Why is `yaourt/pacman` suggesting me to downgrade my package?
- Will downgrading my package actually solve my `ntp` problem or should I rather downgrade `openssl` assuming there to be the right `libcrypto.so` version?

#### Edit 1

I have a second arch linux box I also upgraded today where I dont have the issue. Here are the two `pacman.log`'s in comparison. Might shed also some light on this:

```
BoxRunningFine# cat /var/log/pacman.log | grep -e "upgraded openssl" -e "upgraded ntp"
[2017-01-04 21:26] [ALPM] upgraded ntp (4.2.8.p8-1 -> 4.2.8.p9-1)
[2017-02-28 19:05] [ALPM] upgraded openssl (1.0.2.j-1 -> 1.0.2.k-1)
[2017-04-24 18:48] [ALPM] upgraded openssl (1.0.2.k-1 -> 1.1.0.e-1)
[2017-04-24 18:49] [ALPM] upgraded ntp (4.2.8.p9-1 -> 4.2.8.p9-2)


BoxWithIssue# cat /var/log/pacman.log | grep -e "upgraded ntp" -e "upgraded openssl"
[2016-06-05 03:18] [ALPM] upgraded ntp (4.2.8.p7-1 -> 4.2.8.p8-1)
[2016-10-21 18:17] [ALPM] upgraded openssl (1.0.2.h-1 -> 1.0.2.j-1)
[2017-01-06 14:18] [ALPM] upgraded ntp (4.2.8.p8-1 -> 4.2.8.p9-1)
[2017-02-08 22:54] [ALPM] upgraded openssl (1.0.2.j-1 -> 1.0.2.k-1)
[2017-04-13 18:08] [ALPM] upgraded ntp (4.2.8.p9-1 -> 4.2.8.p10-1)
[2017-04-24 19:23] [ALPM] upgraded openssl (1.0.2.k-1 -> 1.1.0.e-1)
```

By the looks of it the upgrading timing on the box with the issues was just poor. Guess that would be a classic case of bad luck. So then I just downgrade to `4.2.8.p9-2` and it should be fine I reckon?

#### Edit 2

```
# yaourt -Sy ntp
warning: downgrading package ntp (4.2.8.p10-1 => 4.2.8.p9-2)
Packages (1) ntp-4.2.8.p9-2
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 ntp-4.2.8.p9-2-x86_64
(1/1) downgrading ntp                             

# systemctl start ntpd && systemctl status ntpd
● ntpd.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-04-24 21:14:41 CEST; 5s ago

# yaourt -Qi ntp
Name            : ntp
Version         : 4.2.8.p9-2

# systemctl status | grep -m1 State:
State: running
```

Problem solved. Downgrading to *ntp-4.2.8.p9-**2*** was the solution. Thanks for the help and providing the according resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like [this bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/53791?project=1&cat%5B0%5D=2&string=ntp) which reads:

> 4.2.8.p10-1 has been replaced with 4.2.8.p9-2 apparently by the openssl rebuild.

I assume that [the rebuild for the OpenSSL update](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/ntp&id=90c79a18f446b05c0d49db27834755e714696a7c) was in staging long enough to be superseded in the meantime by [the update for a new upstream release](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/ntp&id=b150d722238dce83352d3b9dad13ec5cef5b6963), but then when the OpenSSL rebuild was moved from staging to community, the package with the lower version number replaced the one with the higher one.

Edit: It looks like [4.2.8.p10-2](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/ntp&id=45e12ab72bfce709987284d375adfa1175c95648) has already been uploaded to correct this situation.

Comment: That makes sense. I also overlooked the difference in the versions from `p9-1` to `p9-2`. In light of those circumstances the downgrade should resolve this issue since I am not downgrading to my previous `ntp`version but the `p9-2`. I'll give it a try and report the outcome.

Comment: While I was downgrading to `p9-2` they actually brought up the fix to `p10-2`? Well I guess time for a second round of updating/upgrading - then again the mirrors probably have to catch up syncing -. Thanks for status update as the package version changed during the course of this troubleshooting session.